Domain change, 301 Redirects, Site Map & Indexing
I changed my old domain name to a shorter domain name. I set up 301 redirects and uploaded the XML site map of the new website to Google Search Console. Google indexed the new domain, but I still see the old domain in the search as well. Should I delete the old website's site map from Google Search Console and keep only the new site map in there?

Yes you’ll need to remove the old site map because now you need to tell Google that your website has been changed its domain. You’ll also need to create internal links again and implement proper redirection. This will at least take a few weeks or two months and once Google understands, your site domain has been changed the rankings and traffic will sustain

While a sitemap does not help much in indexing your site, it does provide links. In this case, unwanted links. So, remove it.
Also, ensure, as far as you can, that each page is referenced with an internal link. A sitemap page where you list the pages is one way to do it.
